# LAN casting slides / spreadsheet to an ubuntu projector

Tags: remote-access, rdp, projector

A VGA projector is connected to a laptop-docking-bay (LAN connected), that is configured dual boot with 16.04 / Windows XP I would like to boot into 16.04 to display the desktop of aLAN connected Windows 10 box or another instance of 16.04.

Is there simple and clever means of performing this task.  I am also open to an RDP equivalent if that is simpler.  The goal is to show a few slides and spreadsheets on a projector.